# Issue with OpenOffice, JOD Converter, Docsplit on CentOS

Tags: java, linux, centos, openoffice.org, centos5

I've followed the directions to install Docsplit from here (accounting for differences for CentOS of course): http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit

I think I've got all necessary packages installed, but when I run "docsplit pdf " to convert a Word Doc to PDF, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: failed to start and connect
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:61)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.PooledOfficeManager.start(PooledOfficeManager.java:102)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ProcessPoolOfficeManager.start(ProcessPoolOfficeManager.java:59)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.cli.Convert.main(Convert.java:98)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not establish connection
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.startAndWait(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:59)
 ... 3 more
Caused by: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeException: could not establish connection
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.doStartProcessAndConnect(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:123)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.access$000(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:31)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess$1.run(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:55)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.RetryTimeoutException: java.net.ConnectException: connection failed: 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'; java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.Retryable.execute(Retryable.java:48)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.Retryable.execute(Retryable.java:31)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess.doStartProcessAndConnect(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:113)
 ... 8 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: connection failed: 'socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=2002,tcpNoDelay=1'; java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.OfficeConnection.connect(OfficeConnection.java:101)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.ManagedOfficeProcess$6.attempt(ManagedOfficeProcess.java:116)
 at org.artofsolving.jodconverter.office.Retryable.execute(Retryable.java:41)
 ... 10 more
```

For what it's worth, I had all of this working perfectly both in OS X and in an Ubuntu VM I set up.  But CentOS is giving me a lot of grief with this stuff. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in red hat,I installed openoffice.org-headless-***.rpm package and all ok.

Answer (score -1):

You could try [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) or JODConverter to help also.  They both sit over openoffice to produce documents.